# What does the notation $Z \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ stand for in statistics?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

What does the notation $Z \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ stand for in statistics?

I was reading an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124644/what-is-the-probability-that-a-girl-is-taller-than-a-boy-with-boys-n68-4-5/124646?newreg=10a503454fc54527b2429f6541b0d24f) in stats exchange and a user mentioned that. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ means that $Z$ follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

Comment: That's what the ∼(, 2) means?

Comment: Yes, edited for clarity

Comment: Can I understand it to mean $PDF_Z = N(\mu,\sigma^2)$? That is, they're equal functions, i.e. $\forall x. PDF_Z(x) = N(\mu,\sigma^2)(x)$?

Comment: And if the right-hand-side is a discrete distribution, I suppose it means the PMF instead of PDF? E.g. $Z \sim Binomial(n,p)$ means $PMF_Z = Binomial(n,p)$?